# Longtable disconfigures after second objetive

Tags: longtable

I have the following code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.5\linewidth}|p{0.5\linewidth}|}
\caption{Métodos Seleccionados por Objetivo Específico} \label{tab:long} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Objetivo Específico}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Métodos Seleccionados}} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Objetivo Específico}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Métodos Seleccionados}} \\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\hline
\endfoot

Desarrolar una aplicacion con una interfaz intuitiva y amigable para que los usuarios puedan navegar y utilizar la aplicación sin dificultades. & Métodos de Investigación Empírica:
                \begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
                    \item Realizar pruebas de usabilidad con usuarios potenciales para evaluar la interfaz y la experiencia de usuario, identificando áreas de mejora y garantizando la intuición y amigabilidad.
                    \item Conducir entrevistas con los usuarios actuales de aplicaciones similares para comprender sus experiencias, preferencias y desafíos en la navegación de interfaces.
                \end{itemize}
                Métodos de Desarrollo de Software:
                \begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
                    \item Utilizar herramientas de diseño de interfaz de usuario (UI) para crear un diseño intuitivo y fácil de usar, tomando en cuenta las mejores prácticas en diseño de aplicaciones móviles.
                    \item Implementar pruebas de usabilidad periódicas durante el desarrollo para iterar y mejorar la interfaz en función de la retroalimentación de los usuarios.
                    \item Integrar características de navegación sencilla y menús intuitivos en la aplicación para facilitar la interacción del usuario.
                    \item Aplicar principios de diseño centrado en el usuario para garantizar que la interfaz sea amigable y se adapte a las necesidades y expectativas de los usuarios.
                \end{itemize}
\\

Permitir el acceso al historial médico, cartilla de vacunas y tratamientos de la mascota o mascotas del usuario de manera sencilla y rápida. & Métodos de Investigación Empírica:
            \begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
                \item Realizar encuestas o entrevistas con usuarios para comprender sus necesidades específicas con respecto al acceso y gestión del historial médico de sus mascotas.
                \item Analizar aplicaciones similares o plataformas existentes que ofrecen servicios de gestión de historiales médicos de mascotas, identificando características eficientes y áreas de posible mejora.
            \end{itemize}

            Métodos de Desarrollo de Software:
            \begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
                \item Desarrollar una interfaz de usuario intuitiva que permita a los usuarios acceder fácilmente al historial médico, cartilla de vacunas y tratamientos de sus mascotas. 
                \item Implementar funciones de búsqueda y filtrado eficientes para que los usuarios puedan encontrar rápidamente la información específica que están buscando.
                \item Utilizar tecnologías de almacenamiento seguro para proteger la privacidad y seguridad de la información médica de las mascotas almacenada en la aplicación.
                \item Incorporar notificaciones y recordatorios automáticos para alertar a los usuarios sobre fechas importantes, como vacunas programadas o tratamientos médicos planificados.
                \item Realizar pruebas de usabilidad con usuarios para evaluar la eficacia y la facilidad de uso de la funcionalidad de acceso al historial médico, realizando ajustes según sea necesario.
            \end{itemize}
            \\
\hline
Proporcionar notificaciones y recordatorios automáticos para citas médicas, vacunas y otras necesidades de salud de las mascotas. & Métodos de Investigación Empírica:
            \begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
                \item Realizar encuestas o entrevistas con usuarios para comprender sus preferencias y necesidades específicas en cuanto a notificaciones y recordatorios para la salud de sus mascotas.
                \item Analizar aplicaciones similares o servicios existentes que ofrezcan notificaciones y recordatorios para citas médicas, vacunas y otras necesidades de salud de mascotas, identificando mejores prácticas y posibles áreas de mejora.
            \end{itemize}

            Métodos de Desarrollo de Software:
            \begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
                \item Desarrollar un sistema de notificaciones y recordatorios automáticos integrado en la aplicación para alertar a los usuarios sobre citas médicas, vacunas y otras necesidades de salud de sus mascotas.
                \item Permitir a los usuarios personalizar sus preferencias de notificación, como la frecuencia y el formato de los recordatorios, para adaptarse a sus rutinas y preferencias individuales.
                \item Implementar una interfaz de usuario clara y accesible que permita a los usuarios gestionar y ajustar fácilmente sus configuraciones de notificación.
                \item Utilizar tecnologías de sincronización y almacenamiento seguro para garantizar la precisión y actualización de las notificaciones en tiempo real.
                \item Realizar pruebas de usabilidad con usuarios para evaluar la efectividad y la usabilidad del sistema de notificaciones, realizando ajustes según sea necesario.
            \end{itemize} 
            \\
\hline
Desarrollar una sección para reportar animales extraviados y encontrados. De esta forma se creará una especie de red social, la cual será únicamente de mascotas, para que así las personas puedan solicitar ayuda o notificar sobre alguna mascota perdida. 
& Métodos de Investigación Empírica:
            \begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
                \item Realizar entrevistas con potenciales usuarios de la sección de reportes para comprender sus necesidades y expectativas al buscar o reportar mascotas extraviadas.
                \item nvestigar plataformas similares de reporte de mascotas extraviadas y encontradas para identificar características exitosas y áreas de mejora.
            \end{itemize}

            Métodos de Desarrollo de Software:
            \begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
                \item Desarrollar una interfaz intuitiva y fácil de usar para la sección de reportes, permitiendo a los usuarios registrar información sobre mascotas perdidas o encontradas de manera eficiente.
                \item Integrar funciones de búsqueda y filtrado en la sección para facilitar a los usuarios la localización de animales extraviados según criterios específicos.
                \item Implementar un sistema de notificaciones para informar a los usuarios sobre mascotas perdidas o encontradas que coincidan con sus preferencias y ubicación.
                \item Establecer medidas de seguridad y privacidad para proteger la información sensible proporcionada por los usuarios al reportar mascotas extraviadas.
                \item Facilitar la comunicación entre usuarios a través de la plataforma, permitiendo solicitudes de ayuda, intercambio de información y colaboración en la búsqueda de mascotas perdidas.
                \item Realizar pruebas de usabilidad con usuarios para evaluar la eficacia y la experiencia de usuario de la sección de reportes, realizando ajustes según sea necesario.
            \end{itemize}
            \\ 
\hline
Cumplir con los requisitos de graduación establecidos por la Universidad Privada Boliviana a través de un proyecto de grado y la defensa de este. & Elaboración del documento académico exigido por la universidad. \\ 
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

The first objetivo especifo fits fine, however after that the second , third and fourth are cropped and overlap with the page footnote, how can i fix that?
My problem looks something like this

[image]
[image]

Comment: never put longtable in a `center` but also tables can only break between rows so your long itemize lists can not break over a page. You would be better to set this as a list rather than a table

Comment: It's a paper I'm doing for university and it's their requirement to present this part as  a table.

Comment: if you provided an example we could debug the page breaking, but otherwise use `\clearpage` before the row with the list so that the list comes at the top of the next page or better don't use itemize, place each bullet point in its own row of the longtable so that page breaking can happen between items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with the earlier comments that the material at hand is not exactly well suited for display in a table.

However, if you absolutely, positively *must* use a table, I suggest you (a) switch from a `longtable` to an `xltabular` environment (both to simplify column-width calculations and to assure that the table will fit inside the textblock), (b) use uneven column widths (in the example below, the second column's usable width is 50% greater than that of the first column), (c) employ a bespoke itemize-like environment (called `tabitemize` in the example below) that typesets its contents compactly, and (d) get rid of all vertical rules and most horizontal rules in order to give the table a welcoming 'look'.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex % pdfLaTeX is in use
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\else % either XeLateX or LuaLaTeX is in use
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
\fi

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet,left=0pt,nosep,
    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
    after ={\end{minipage}}}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} L{0.8} L{1.2} @{} } 
   % Note: 0.8 + 1.2 = 2 = number of X-type columns
   

%% headers and footers

\caption{Métodos seleccionados por objetivo específico} 
\label{tablong} \\
\toprule
Objetivo específico & Métodos seleccionados \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}%
   {\tablename~\thetable, continuación} \\[0.75ex]
\toprule
Objetivo específico & Métodos seleccionados \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{\footnotesize continúa en la siguiente página} \\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


%% body of table

Desarrollar una aplicacion con una interfaz intuitiva y amigable para que los usuarios puedan navegar y utilizar la aplicación sin dificultades. 
& 
Métodos de investigación empírica
\begin{tabitemize}
   \item Realizar pruebas de usabilidad con usuarios potenciales para evaluar la interfaz y la experiencia de usuario, identificando áreas de mejora y garantizando la intuición y amigabilidad.
   \item Conducir entrevistas con los usuarios actuales de aplicaciones similares para comprender sus experiencias, preferencias y desafíos en la navegación de interfaces.
\end{tabitemize} 
\\ \addlinespace
&
Métodos de desarrollo de software
\begin{tabitemize}
   \item Utilizar herramientas de diseño de interfaz de usuario (UI) para crear un diseño intuitivo y fácil de usar, tomando en cuenta las mejores prácticas en diseño de aplicaciones móviles.
   \item Implementar pruebas de usabilidad periódicas durante el desarrollo para iterar y mejorar la interfaz en función de la retroalimentación de los usuarios.
   \item Integrar características de navegación sencilla y menús intuitivos en la aplicación para facilitar la interacción del usuario.
   \item Aplicar principios de diseño centrado en el usuario para garantizar que la interfaz sea amigable y se adapte a las necesidades y expectativas de los usuarios.
\end{tabitemize}
\\ \addlinespace

Permitir el acceso al historial médico, cartilla de vacunas y tratamientos de la mascota o mascotas del usuario de manera sencilla y rápida. 
& 
Métodos de investigación empírica
\begin{tabitemize}
   \item Realizar encuestas o entrevistas con usuarios para comprender sus necesidades específicas con respecto al acceso y gestión del historial médico de sus mascotas.
   \item Analizar aplicaciones similares o plataformas existentes que ofrecen servicios de gestión de historiales médicos de mascotas, identificando características eficientes y áreas de posible mejora.
\end{tabitemize} 
\\ \addlinespace
&
Métodos de desarrollo de software
\begin{tabitemize}
   \item Desarrollar una interfaz de usuario intuitiva que permita a los usuarios acceder fácilmente al historial médico, cartilla de vacunas y tratamientos de sus mascotas. 
   \item Implementar funciones de búsqueda y filtrado eficientes para que los usuarios puedan encontrar rápidamente la información específica que están buscando.
   \item Utilizar tecnologías de almacenamiento seguro para proteger la privacidad y seguridad de la información médica de las mascotas almacenada en la aplicación.
   \item Incorporar notificaciones y recordatorios automáticos para alertar a los usuarios sobre fechas importantes, como vacunas programadas o tratamientos médicos planificados.
   \item Realizar pruebas de usabilidad con usuarios para evaluar la eficacia y la facilidad de uso de la funcionalidad de acceso al historial médico, realizando ajustes según sea necesario.
\end{tabitemize}
\\ %\addlinespace

Proporcionar notificaciones y recordatorios automáticos para citas médicas, vacunas y otras necesidades de salud de las mascotas. 
& 
Métodos de investigación empírica
\begin{tabitemize}
   \item Realizar encuestas o entrevistas con usuarios para comprender sus preferencias y necesidades específicas en cuanto a notificaciones y recordatorios para la salud de sus mascotas.
   \item Analizar aplicaciones similares o servicios existentes que ofrezcan notificaciones y recordatorios para citas médicas, vacunas y otras necesidades de salud de mascotas, identificando mejores prácticas y posibles áreas de mejora.
\end{tabitemize}
\\ \addlinespace
&
Métodos de desarrollo de software
\begin{tabitemize}
   \item Desarrollar un sistema de notificaciones y recordatorios automáticos integrado en la aplicación para alertar a los usuarios sobre citas médicas, vacunas y otras necesidades de salud de sus mascotas.
   \item Permitir a los usuarios personalizar sus preferencias de notificación, como la frecuencia y el formato de los recordatorios, para adaptarse a sus rutinas y preferencias individuales.
   \item Implementar una interfaz de usuario clara y accesible que permita a los usuarios gestionar y ajustar fácilmente sus configuraciones de notificación.
   \item Utilizar tecnologías de sincronización y almacenamiento seguro para garantizar la precisión y actualización de las notificaciones en tiempo real.
   \item Realizar pruebas de usabilidad con usuarios para evaluar la efectividad y la usabilidad del sistema de notificaciones, realizando ajustes según sea necesario.
\end{tabitemize} 
\\ \addlinespace

Desarrollar una sección para reportar animales extraviados y encontrados. De esta forma se creará una especie de red social, la cual será únicamente de mascotas, para que así las personas puedan solicitar ayuda o notificar sobre alguna mascota perdida. 
& 
Métodos de investigación empírica
\begin{tabitemize}
   \item Realizar entrevistas con potenciales usuarios de la sección de reportes para comprender sus necesidades y expectativas al buscar o reportar mascotas extraviadas.
   \item Investigar plataformas similares de reporte de mascotas extraviadas y encontradas para identificar características exitosas y áreas de mejora.
\end{tabitemize}
\\ \addlinespace
&
Métodos de desarrollo de software
\begin{tabitemize}
   \item Desarrollar una interfaz intuitiva y fácil de usar para la sección de reportes, permitiendo a los usuarios registrar información sobre mascotas perdidas o encontradas de manera eficiente.
   \item Integrar funciones de búsqueda y filtrado en la sección para facilitar a los usuarios la localización de animales extraviados según criterios específicos.
   \item Implementar un sistema de notificaciones para informar a los usuarios sobre mascotas perdidas o encontradas que coincidan con sus preferencias y ubicación.
\end{tabitemize} \\
&
\begin{tabitemize}
   \item Establecer medidas de seguridad y privacidad para proteger la información sensible proporcionada por los usuarios al reportar mascotas extraviadas.
   \item Facilitar la comunicación entre usuarios a través de la plataforma, permitiendo solicitudes de ayuda, intercambio de información y colaboración en la búsqueda de mascotas perdidas.
   \item Realizar pruebas de usabilidad con usuarios para evaluar la eficacia y la experiencia de usuario de la sección de reportes, realizando ajustes según sea necesario.
\end{tabitemize}
\\ \addlinespace

Cumplir con los requisitos de graduación establecidos por la Universidad Privada Boliviana a través de un proyecto de grado y la defensa de este. 
& 
Elaboración del documento académico exigido por la universidad. \\ 

\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```